# Look "inside" a GPG key block?

Tags: gnupg

PGP/GPG keys have those begin and end lines, and are encoded with something like base64 (radix-64 apparently).

But what exactly is inside the data block? Are there some tools for how to display the data there, or how would I do that? Running it through `base64 -D` does not produce anything I can recognize.

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

mQENBFw3w4QBCADPb+endNe85cmQmVpmstAKdNKmLIGABAMJmDVq9IocrrlPIpKK
9A1dc8KOE9DC6TEt1L+LAZ9KQ684/wTVo9IteGtfKA47UZPDgsKVMBIN+2/nIwYL
...
/3VLiO5HuiO9h6KdVQRXZ/pZbSutt1K1CCy1yY+c6g==
=sYPk
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Comment: I would assume it's a base64 representation of the key itself, with the amount of base64 data, entirely dependant on the size of the key (i.e. 1024, 2056, ect)

Comment: If you're using or otherwise have `gpg` just do [`--list-packets`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Operational-GPG-Commands.html#Operational-GPG-Commands)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a GPG decoder here: https://cirw.in/gpg-decoder/

It tells you things like the creation time, algorithm used, user ID, info about subkeys if they're in there, all that good stuff. Not sure on what is done for decoding but the source code is available if you want to take a look at how they did it.

Source code: https://github.com/ConradIrwin/gpg-decoder

Answer (score 0):

[`pgpdump`](https://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/pgpdump/en/) is a command line PGP packet visualiser that displays the packet format of OpenPGP (RFC 4880) and PGP version 2 (RFC 1991).